# Trying to get city name from json but getting null return

Tags: json, dart

I am new to dart and following a this post to get my data from json:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/converting-json-into-class-objects-in-dart-abcc3cc05478

I am getting weather data from api source which gives me to much info.  I only want city name first, then onto try get current temp of that city, i pass into api.

i using https://jsonformatter.org/json-to-dart to format into classes.

I just trying to get city name first from json.  but getting null return.  It is due to City is a MAP???

name = city

i am getting all the data back with 200 response

jsonclass.dart

code:import 'dart:convert';

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'apikey.dart';
import 'jasonclasscity.dart';

class WeatherApiException implements Exception {
  const WeatherApiException(this.message);
  final String message;
}

void main() async {
  String url =
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Palm%20Springs&units=imperial';

  final httpUrl = Uri.parse('$url$appid');
  final response = await http.get(httpUrl);
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);

    throw WeatherApiException('Error getting city: xxxxx');
  }
  print(response.statusCode);
  var body = response.body;
    print(response.body);
  City city = City.fromJson(jsonDecode(body.toString()));

  print(city.toString());
}
```

jsonclasscity.dart

```
class City {
  // final int id;
  final String name; //need this
  // final Coord coord;
  // final String country;
  // final int population;
  // final int timezone;
  // final int sunrise;
  // final int sunset;

  City(
      {
      // required this.id,
      required this.name
      //required this.coord,
      //required this.country,
      //required this.population,
      //required this.timezone,
      //required this.sunrise,
      //required this.sunset,
      });

  factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    return City(
    name: json ["name"],
     
    ); // City
  }
}

class Coord {
  final double lat;
  final double lon;

  Coord({
    required this.lat,
    required this.lon,
  });
}

class MainClass {
  MainClass({
    required this.temp, //need this
    required this.feelsLike,
    required this.tempMin,
    required this.tempMax,
    required this.pressure,
    required this.seaLevel,
    required this.grndLevel,
    required this.humidity,
    required this.tempKf,
  });

  final double temp;
  final double feelsLike;
  final double tempMin;
  final double tempMax;
  final int pressure;
  final int seaLevel;
  final int grndLevel;
  final int humidity;
  final double tempKf;
}
```

json api data back from call:

```
{"cod":"200","message":0,"cnt":40,"list":[{"dt":1662498000,"main":{"temp":107.73,"feels_like":106.95,"temp_min":107.73,"temp_max":110.3,"pressure":1009,"sea_level":1009,"grnd_level":995,"humidity":18,"temp_kf":-1.43},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":8.03,"deg":123,"gust":8.99},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-06 21:00:00"},{"dt":1662508800,"main":{"temp":108.37,"feels_like":107.17,"temp_min":108.37,"temp_max":109.33,"pressure":1009,"sea_level":1009,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":17,"temp_kf":-0.53},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":1},"wind":{"speed":7.38,"deg":129,"gust":6.78},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-07 00:00:00"},{"dt":1662519600,"main":{"temp":99.99,"feels_like":99.14,"temp_min":99.99,"temp_max":99.99,"pressure":1011,"sea_level":1011,"grnd_level":995,"humidity":24,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":4},"wind":{"speed":0.94,"deg":283,"gust":4.56},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-07 03:00:00"},{"dt":1662530400,"main":{"temp":95.72,"feels_like":95.07,"temp_min":95.72,"temp_max":95.72,"pressure":1013,"sea_level":1013,"grnd_level":997,"humidity":29,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":2},"wind":{"speed":0.25,"deg":324,"gust":3.56},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-07 06:00:00"},{"dt":1662541200,"main":{"temp":91.53,"feels_like":91.89,"temp_min":91.53,"temp_max":91.53,"pressure":1014,"sea_level":1014,"grnd_level":998,"humidity":37,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.33,"deg":90,"gust":4.29},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-07 09:00:00"},{"dt":1662552000,"main":{"temp":87.82,"feels_like":89.73,"temp_min":87.82,"temp_max":87.82,"pressure":1014,"sea_level":1014,"grnd_level":998,"humidity":47,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":1.9,"deg":95,"gust":3.31},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-07 12:00:00"},{"dt":1662562800,"main":{"temp":87.26,"feels_like":94.03,"temp_min":87.26,"temp_max":87.26,"pressure":1017,"sea_level":1017,"grnd_level":1000,"humidity":61,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":4.27,"deg":94,"gust":5.46},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-07 15:00:00"},{"dt":1662573600,"main":{"temp":94.55,"feels_like":100.96,"temp_min":94.55,"temp_max":94.55,"pressure":1016,"sea_level":1016,"grnd_level":1000,"humidity":45,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":5.3,"deg":103,"gust":6.13},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-07 18:00:00"},{"dt":1662584400,"main":{"temp":101.66,"feels_like":102.16,"temp_min":101.66,"temp_max":101.66,"pressure":1014,"sea_level":1014,"grnd_level":998,"humidity":25,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":5.75,"deg":98,"gust":8.25},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-07 21:00:00"},{"dt":1662595200,"main":{"temp":102.78,"feels_like":101.17,"temp_min":102.78,"temp_max":102.78,"pressure":1012,"sea_level":1012,"grnd_level":996,"humidity":20,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":6.42,"deg":117,"gust":7.74},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-08 00:00:00"},{"dt":1662606000,"main":{"temp":96.26,"feels_like":96.26,"temp_min":96.26,"temp_max":96.26,"pressure":1013,"sea_level":1013,"grnd_level":997,"humidity":30,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":5.26,"deg":117,"gust":6.46},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-08 03:00:00"},{"dt":1662616800,"main":{"temp":93.09,"feels_like":92.77,"temp_min":93.09,"temp_max":93.09,"pressure":1013,"sea_level":1013,"grnd_level":997,"humidity":33,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.75,"deg":280,"gust":3.29},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-08 06:00:00"},{"dt":1662627600,"main":{"temp":91.8,"feels_like":90.66,"temp_min":91.8,"temp_max":91.8,"pressure":1011,"sea_level":1011,"grnd_level":995,"humidity":32,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":4.63,"deg":296,"gust":5.26},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-08 09:00:00"},{"dt":1662638400,"main":{"temp":82.94,"feels_like":86.76,"temp_min":82.94,"temp_max":82.94,"pressure":1012,"sea_level":1012,"grnd_level":996,"humidity":64,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.04,"deg":31,"gust":3.67},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-08 12:00:00"},{"dt":1662649200,"main":{"temp":86.65,"feels_like":91.22,"temp_min":86.65,"temp_max":86.65,"pressure":1012,"sea_level":1012,"grnd_level":996,"humidity":57,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":4.79,"deg":111,"gust":5.73},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-08 15:00:00"},{"dt":1662660000,"main":{"temp":91.9,"feels_like":97.29,"temp_min":91.9,"temp_max":91.9,"pressure":1010,"sea_level":1010,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":48,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":38},"wind":{"speed":5.3,"deg":97,"gust":4.43},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-08 18:00:00"},{"dt":1662670800,"main":{"temp":99.64,"feels_like":102.29,"temp_min":99.64,"temp_max":99.64,"pressure":1007,"sea_level":1007,"grnd_level":991,"humidity":31,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":82},"wind":{"speed":6.49,"deg":103,"gust":7.18},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-08 21:00:00"},{"dt":1662681600,"main":{"temp":98.38,"feels_like":100.67,"temp_min":98.38,"temp_max":98.38,"pressure":1004,"sea_level":1004,"grnd_level":989,"humidity":32,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":91},"wind":{"speed":4.27,"deg":115,"gust":5.57},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-09 00:00:00"},{"dt":1662692400,"main":{"temp":94.01,"feels_like":96.22,"temp_min":94.01,"temp_max":94.01,"pressure":1005,"sea_level":1005,"grnd_level":989,"humidity":38,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":98},"wind":{"speed":0.43,"deg":302,"gust":2.59},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.08,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-09 03:00:00"},{"dt":1662703200,"main":{"temp":91.24,"feels_like":92.17,"temp_min":91.24,"temp_max":91.24,"pressure":1004,"sea_level":1004,"grnd_level":988,"humidity":39,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":98},"wind":{"speed":3.06,"deg":286,"gust":3.47},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-09 06:00:00"},{"dt":1662714000,"main":{"temp":81.39,"feels_like":83.91,"temp_min":81.39,"temp_max":81.39,"pressure":1006,"sea_level":1006,"grnd_level":990,"humidity":62,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":4.63,"deg":62,"gust":6.29},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-09 09:00:00"},{"dt":1662724800,"main":{"temp":79,"feels_like":79,"temp_min":79,"temp_max":79,"pressure":1005,"sea_level":1005,"grnd_level":989,"humidity":71,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":2.51,"deg":60,"gust":4.79},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-09 12:00:00"},{"dt":1662735600,"main":{"temp":80.55,"feels_like":83.55,"temp_min":80.55,"temp_max":80.55,"pressure":1006,"sea_level":1006,"grnd_level":990,"humidity":68,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":3.8,"deg":64,"gust":5.48},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-09 15:00:00"},{"dt":1662746400,"main":{"temp":87.75,"feels_like":90.99,"temp_min":87.75,"temp_max":87.75,"pressure":1006,"sea_level":1006,"grnd_level":990,"humidity":51,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":8.95,"deg":91,"gust":17.07},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-09 18:00:00"},{"dt":1662757200,"main":{"temp":83.46,"feels_like":87.93,"temp_min":83.46,"temp_max":83.46,"pressure":1005,"sea_level":1005,"grnd_level":989,"humidity":65,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":9.75,"deg":102,"gust":15.77},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.16,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-09 21:00:00"},{"dt":1662768000,"main":{"temp":80.98,"feels_like":84.6,"temp_min":80.98,"temp_max":80.98,"pressure":1004,"sea_level":1004,"grnd_level":988,"humidity":70,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":9.42,"deg":79,"gust":24.18},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.37,"rain":{"3h":1.03},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-10 00:00:00"},{"dt":1662778800,"main":{"temp":76.71,"feels_like":78.13,"temp_min":76.71,"temp_max":76.71,"pressure":1004,"sea_level":1004,"grnd_level":988,"humidity":86,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":10.13,"deg":16,"gust":15.84},"visibility":3866,"pop":0.88,"rain":{"3h":8.03},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-10 03:00:00"},{"dt":1662789600,"main":{"temp":77.85,"feels_like":79.41,"temp_min":77.85,"temp_max":77.85,"pressure":1005,"sea_level":1005,"grnd_level":989,"humidity":87,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":502,"main":"Rain","description":"heavy intensity rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":8.9,"deg":67,"gust":15.05},"visibility":2520,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":13.28},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-10 06:00:00"},{"dt":1662800400,"main":{"temp":76.24,"feels_like":78.08,"temp_min":76.24,"temp_max":76.24,"pressure":1005,"sea_level":1005,"grnd_level":988,"humidity":96,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":502,"main":"Rain","description":"heavy intensity rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":8.21,"deg":85,"gust":12.82},"visibility":284,"pop":0.99,"rain":{"3h":14.58},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-10 09:00:00"},{"dt":1662811200,"main":{"temp":73.42,"feels_like":74.88,"temp_min":73.42,"temp_max":73.42,"pressure":1007,"sea_level":1007,"grnd_level":991,"humidity":94,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":502,"main":"Rain","description":"heavy intensity rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":6.73,"deg":89,"gust":12.12},"visibility":519,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":18.39},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-10 12:00:00"},{"dt":1662822000,"main":{"temp":74.17,"feels_like":75.52,"temp_min":74.17,"temp_max":74.17,"pressure":1010,"sea_level":1010,"grnd_level":993,"humidity":90,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":4.45,"deg":82,"gust":7.65},"visibility":853,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":2.28},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-10 15:00:00"},{"dt":1662832800,"main":{"temp":76.66,"feels_like":77.92,"temp_min":76.66,"temp_max":76.66,"pressure":1011,"sea_level":1011,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":83,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":99},"wind":{"speed":5.95,"deg":98,"gust":10.58},"visibility":4886,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":1.15},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-10 18:00:00"},{"dt":1662843600,"main":{"temp":79.83,"feels_like":79.83,"temp_min":79.83,"temp_max":79.83,"pressure":1010,"sea_level":1010,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":73,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":99},"wind":{"speed":4.59,"deg":98,"gust":9.37},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.75,"rain":{"3h":1.11},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-10 21:00:00"},{"dt":1662854400,"main":{"temp":80.85,"feels_like":84.36,"temp_min":80.85,"temp_max":80.85,"pressure":1009,"sea_level":1009,"grnd_level":993,"humidity":70,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":99},"wind":{"speed":5.14,"deg":108,"gust":7.31},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.84,"rain":{"3h":1.43},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-11 00:00:00"},{"dt":1662865200,"main":{"temp":79.84,"feels_like":79.84,"temp_min":79.84,"temp_max":79.84,"pressure":1011,"sea_level":1011,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":72,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":3.36,"deg":117,"gust":5.55},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.83,"rain":{"3h":0.84},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-11 03:00:00"},{"dt":1662876000,"main":{"temp":79.72,"feels_like":79.72,"temp_min":79.72,"temp_max":79.72,"pressure":1012,"sea_level":1012,"grnd_level":996,"humidity":73,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":98},"wind":{"speed":1.03,"deg":40,"gust":3.29},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.75,"rain":{"3h":0.16},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-11 06:00:00"},{"dt":1662886800,"main":{"temp":79.48,"feels_like":79.48,"temp_min":79.48,"temp_max":79.48,"pressure":1012,"sea_level":1012,"grnd_level":995,"humidity":72,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":95},"wind":{"speed":2.1,"deg":84,"gust":4.72},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.05,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-11 09:00:00"},{"dt":1662897600,"main":{"temp":79.5,"feels_like":79.5,"temp_min":79.5,"temp_max":79.5,"pressure":1012,"sea_level":1012,"grnd_level":996,"humidity":73,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":96},"wind":{"speed":3.47,"deg":104,"gust":4.63},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.08,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-11 12:00:00"},{"dt":1662908400,"main":{"temp":79.7,"feels_like":79.7,"temp_min":79.7,"temp_max":79.7,"pressure":1014,"sea_level":1014,"grnd_level":998,"humidity":73,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":99},"wind":{"speed":3.13,"deg":96,"gust":4.18},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.05,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-11 15:00:00"},{"dt":1662919200,"main":{"temp":84.87,"feels_like":88.41,"temp_min":84.87,"temp_max":84.87,"pressure":1014,"sea_level":1014,"grnd_level":998,"humidity":58,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":84},"wind":{"speed":4.52,"deg":94,"gust":5.99},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.03,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2022-09-11 18:00:00"}],"city":{"id":5380668,"name":"Palm Springs","coord":{"lat":33.8303,"lon":-116.5453},"country":"US","population":44552,"timezone":-25200,"sunrise":1662470615,"sunset":1662516349}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not dug into your code, but I can pretty much guarantee that your issue will be down to you not querying the correct nested level of the JSON Object. Looking at the JSON data you get back from the API call, within the main Object, there is then a 'City' Object, which has the key 'name' against it. Make sure you're querying the correct level.

The structure you need to get the data you need is essentially the following pseudo code: JsonObjectFromAPIResponse.get("city").get("name")

Just translate this into what you're doing. Debug it step by step. You're over complicating it in your code example before you've got the basics working. Forget about the City Objects and Factories you've been creating, just get it working in a single file, then refactor it after.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for response.  i was able to figure out the correct way to walk down the json tree. i was just coding the format incorrect.

this worked

```
print('justcity name:');
 // printout Palm SPrings ok.
    print(data['city']['name']); 

  //print(justList[0]);
  final justTemp = data['list'][0]['main']['temp']; 
  print('justTemp:');
```

this json tool help me understand the json tree better for my very long and complex json response from host api.
https://jsonpathfinder.com/